# Match a Specific combination of values from a one to many relationship mapping table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, combinations

I have a one to many relationship mapping table in postgres and the tables are as below:

**Students**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Shibbir |
| 2 | Ahmed |
| 3 | John |

**Courses**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Data Structure |
| 2 | Algorithms |
| 3 | Math |

**student_course_mapping**

| studentId | courseId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

**Given that**
a student must have unique course combinations:
if student 1 have the course 1,2,3 then none of the other students can have same course combinations, thus student 2 has to to take course combination 2,3 and then finally student 3 has to take course combination 1,2.

**Finally my question is**:
if I have a combination of course ids, then how to write the query to get the unique student id from **student_course_mapping** table who has exactly the same combination of courses.

**example** :
input course ids: 1,2,3 then output should be 1
input course ids: 2,3 then output should be 2
input course ids: 1,2 then output should be 3

It would be great to be able to write a single query that gives the desired result.

Comment: Do a String_Agg() on course ids by student, then you can compare all courses for each student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values position insensitive solution you can use arrays functions and operators - the `ARRAY_AGG` function to create arrays of `courseid` values for each `studentid`, the `@>` operator to check if `courseid` array of a student contains the array of the input `courseid`, the `ARRAY_LENGTH` to check if arrays have equal length.

```
SELECT 
    input.value,
    s.studentid
FROM (VALUES (ARRAY[2, 1, 3]), (ARRAY[2, 3]), (ARRAY[1, 2])) input(value)
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        studentid,
        ARRAY_AGG(courseid) course_ids
    FROM student_course_mapping 
    GROUP BY studentid
) s ON s.course_ids @> input.value AND ARRAY_LENGTH(s.course_ids, 1) = ARRAY_LENGTH(input.value, 1)
```

Output

| value | studentid |
| --- | --- |
| {1,2} | 3 |
| {2,3} | 2 |
| {2,1,3} | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1551ea6e34be6640987fd9ff06139eb0)*

Answer (score 0):

In this case is necessary to create a temporary table because it's not possible to include aggregations in where clause

```
create temp table temp_students_courses
as select s.id, s.name, array_agg(scm.courseid order by courseid) courses 
from students s
inner join student_course_mapping scm on s.id=scm.studentid
group by 1,2;
```

then

```
select t1.*  
from temp_students_courses t1
where exists ( select * 
    from temp_students_courses t2
    where t1.id<>t2.id
    and t1.courses@>t2.courses
    and array_length(t1.courses,1)=array_length(t2.courses,1)
);
```

Since in your sample data doesn't occur the case that you expect, I added an extra row in student_course_mapping to exemplify when two students have same combination of courses.

To test https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tEWNzwHX2YhtuRhoohyh4B/0

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing multiple queries actually. Anyways, Thanks a lot for the solution :)